# Telerik combo background design

Tags: telerik, telerik-combobox

I couldn't figure how to get the combo box looks like the payment method combo box from this link https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx#qsf-demo-source

The source they provide doesn't seems to have any different from each other, but I need that filled combobox design from the 4th one. Just doesn't know how to get it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you press the View Source, then goto 'PaymentMethods.xml' you will see the method used for assigning (Xml taken directly from this [Telerik Demo](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx#qsf-demo-source))

```
<Items>
     <Item Text="American Express" Value="1" ImageUrl="Images/card-types/american-express.png" />
     <Item Text="MasterCard" Value="2" ImageUrl="Images/card-types/mastercard.png" />
     <Item Text="Visa" Value="3" ImageUrl="Images/card-types/visa.png" />
     <Item Text="Visa Electron" Value="4" ImageUrl="Images/card-types/visa-electron.png" />
</Items>
```

There are other methods for adding images using the `ImageUrl` attribute (See this [Telerik Demo](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-appearance-item-images.html))

Alternatively you might want to use the `ItemTemplate` should you want further control (See this [Telerik Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/templates/defaultcs.aspx)) This also allows you to put further details in the drop down list which is particularly useful when you want to display a little more information.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblOptionTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval('ItemTitle') %>' Font-Bold="true" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblOptionText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval('ItemText') %>' />
    <img id="imgOption" alt="Alternative Text" src='<%# Eval('ImageUrl') %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```